# Angular nb-radio (change) not firing when change value

Tags: angular

**Nebular** `checkbox.component.ts` not firing `(change)` event when the value changed.

the `checkbox.component.ts` should have change event

```
 <nb-radio
      [value]="t"
      (change)="onChange($event)"
      *ngFor="let t of tList ">{{t}}</nb-radio>
  </nb-radio-group>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **Nebular** nb-radio dosn't have `(change)` but it has `(valueChange)`
check the source code here [radio.component.ts#L102](https://github.com/akveo/nebular/blob/master/src/framework/theme/components/radio/radio.component.ts#L102)

```
<nb-radio
      [value]="t"
      (valueChange)="onChange($event)"
      *ngFor="let t of tList ">{{t}}</nb-radio>
</nb-radio-group>
```